# Using tty as debug screen without login... How to do it?

Tags: linux, fedora, tty

I need to cast some commands, like `ping 8.8.8.8` on /dev/tty2 ...

Is that posible?
If so, can someone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the ouput of a command directly to the tty of your choice. For example, on most systems TTY8+ are unused. so to ping google's opendns server you could do `ping 8.8.8.8 > /dev/tty8` and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to view the output.

It should be noted you can output to TTYs that are already in use as well... so long as it's a text-mode interface (no piping to TTY7, which generally hosts xwindows). This might be useful if you want leave a command running and the output of a command to appear on the current terminal... but it has the potential of being fairly messy unless carefully implemented.